# Why does if __FILE__ == $0 not work on Heroku with Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I previously had some scripts of this form:

```rb
class Thing
  def do_things
    ...
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  Thing.new.do_things
end
```

I invoked them with `rails runner`. They were working well on Heroku with Rails 5.1. When I upgraded to rails 5.2, they no longer ran on Heroku (silently exiting with the block not being executed). But they do still execute in my dev environment (Ubuntu).

I run them using the relative path to the script (e.g. `rails runner scripts/thing.rb`)

### Rails 5.2

#### Heroku

- `__FILE__`: the absolute path to the script (`/app/scripts/thing.rb`)
- `$0`: the filename (`thing.rb`)

#### Dev Environment (ubuntu)

Both contain just the filename.

### Rails 5.1

In both environments, both contain just the filename.

Comment: When running on Heroku, what is the value of `__FILE__` and `$0`?

Comment: @Stefan I updated the question with more details

Comment: So the difference is that on Heroku with Rails 5.2 the value of `__FILE__` is `"/app/scripts/thing.rb"` and with Rails 5.1 its value was `"thing.rb"`?

Comment: @Stefan yup, exactly

Answer (score 2):

My team ran into this problem when upgrading our app to Rails 5.2 too. We don't use Heroku, so this is an issue with Rails in general instead of Heroku.

When running any Ruby file with `rails runner`, we found that `__FILE` would use an absolute path if `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` was set to "test" or "production", but use a relative path if set to "development" or was unset. Interestingly enough, if the environment was set with the `-e` flag instead, then `__FILE__` would always use a relative path.

We discovered that removing `bootsnap` as a dependency fixed the issue for us. It also means you would have to remove the `require "bootsnap/setup"` line from `config/boot.rb`.

It looks like there may be a bug with regards to how Rails and Bootsnap are both reading environment variables and somehow overwriting how Ruby sets `__FILE__`. Feel free to track this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36550

Comment: I would not recommend removing bootstrap as it will make booting the app slower. You can force the $0 to always be an absolute path by expanding it `File.expand_path($0)`, then you'll get consistent results no matter what environment you run on.